# SSRS Matrix percentage calculation for single row

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a matrix to show pivot values of IN Network and OUT of Network invoices.[image] I need to find 'IN Network total'/'Grand total' as a percentage. my expression is looking like this.
`=switch(Fields!Network_Type.Value="IN Network", Fields!ClientInvoices.Value/sum(Fields!ClientInvoices.Value))`
But I got only values for 2 columns.Could anyone please guide me how to find the percentage at the required row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switch function is usually used for evaluating multiple conditions instead of just one, but would still work in this setting. I think the issue is that you're applying the switch function row by row, and it will only return a value if the condition is true - so if the condition evaluates false for the last row in the set, it gives back nothing. You may wish to structure it so that it sums all of the instances in which the condition evaluates to true, then divide by the overall sum:

```
=sum(switch(Fields!Network_Type.Value="IN Network", Fields!ClientInvoices.Value))/sum(Fields!ClientInvoices.Value)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is all I needed. I suspected the same reason. But I did not know how to fix that.